# Django one to many saving model is giving error

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have an exam model and I am trying to add a form to add multiple Quiz instance in the parent model. I am getting the following error
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot assign "": "exam_quiz.quiz" must be a "Quiz" instance.

```
class ExamQuizAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = exam_quiz
        exclude = ['registrationDate','examdate']



    quiz = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Quiz.objects.all(),
        required=False,
        label=_("Quiz"),
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
            verbose_name=_("Quiz"),
            is_stacked=False))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExamQuizAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.pk:

            self.fields['quiz'].initial = \
                self.instance.quiz

    def save(self, commit=True):
        exam_quiz = super(ExamQuizAdminForm, self).save(commit=False)
        exam_quiz.save()
        exam_quiz.quiz_set.set(self.cleaned_data['Quiz'])

        self.save_m2m()
        return exam_quiz


class ExamQuizAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ExamQuizAdminForm

    list_display = ('examname','month','year')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming exam_quiz.quiz is a m2m field...

I don't think you need to override the save function in this case. Use the save_m2m() function if you want to, say, add additional non form data, and then save both the normal and m2m data from the form.  According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

> "Calling save_m2m() is only required if you use save(commit=False).
> When you use a save() on a form, all data – including many-to-many
> data – is saved without the need for any additional method calls."

Here, however, it looks like the only change you're making is adding the m2m data, which the normal save can handle.

Also, you might try making the Quiz lowercase, eg,

`exam_quiz.quiz_set.set(self.cleaned_data['quiz'])`

as I don't think 'label' or 'verbose_name' affect the HTML field name.